# Horizontal fill in CSS without using floats/clearfixes?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position two DIVs in another container so that the first is against the parent's left edge and the second is against the parent's right edge. Here's the markup I have so far:

```
<div class="parent">
   <p class="flushleft">
        This paragraph should be aligned left.
   </p>
   <p class="flushright">
        This one should be aligned right.
   </p>
</div>
```

How can this be done without using floats? I'd like to keep everything in the normal flow, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some css please.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why they can't be floated?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` in your css code.

Answer (score 1):

Using your HTML, here's the CSS:

```
.flushleft{
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
.flushright{
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Or since they're both identical - if you don't intend to style them further - you can use one class.

Comment: 1+ I made [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/HEEC3/) for you.. I'd suggest throwing `text-align` in there too. See the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/HEEC3/).